# Mp3 player with timer in java [fast forward]

Tags: java, timer, mp3

I'm making fast forward button in my Mp3 player. I wrote already code for this, but have problem how to implement timer to jump 5% forward? I mean when I press button timer should jump 5% forward of total long song. This is my fastForward method.

```
public void FastForward(){
        try {
            //songTotalLength = fis.available();
            fis.skip((long) ((songTotalLength * 0.05)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here is the button method:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        mp3.FastForward();
        if(mp3.player.isComplete()){
            bar = 100;
        }
        jProgressBar1.setValue((int)bar);
        bar+=5;
    }
```

And this one is for timer:

```
private void setTime(float t) {  
        int mili = (int) (t / 1000);
        int sec = (mili / 1000) % 60;
        int min = (mili / 1000) / 60;
        start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        start.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0 + min);
        end.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0 + sec);
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new TimerListener());
        percent = (float)100/(min*60+sec);
    }
```

Comment: What class do you use for playing the MP3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already redundantly tracking progress in two variables `fis` and `bar`. For the sake of good design, use one of those to determine elapsed time rather than using *yet another* variable for the same purpose.

> but have problem how to implement timer to jump 5% forward?

You seem to have mistaken the purpose of a Timer. According to the [`Timer` class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), it:

> Fires one or more ActionEvents at specified intervals.

So the timer is not meant to keep track of how much time has elapsed. It will simply invoke the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method of your `TimerListener` once per second (every 1000 milliseconds) as you have it configured.

For a more complete answer, please post the code for your `TimerListener` class.

**Notes**

- It seems that your `setTime(float)` method is meant to be called repeatedly, so this method should not be initializing the `timer` variable. Rather initialize the timer once and leave it alone to do its job.
- I'm assuming you intended the supplied `float` parameter `t` to represent [microseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).
- The `float` data type has only 7 digits of precision. This could be fine since you're interested only in minutes and seconds, otherwise float is only good for up to about four months of seconds before losing accuracy.
- It seems like you wanted your button click handler to do this (increment `bar` sooner):

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  mp3.FastForward();
  bar+=5; // increment bar before checking complete, and before setting progress
  if(mp3.player.isComplete()){
    bar = 100;
  }
  jProgressBar1.setValue((int)bar);
}
```